# Javascript: Validating if form entries are already submitted to proceed

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, object

so I´m working with this: A form where user(workID and name) submits a claim with a **date**, **positioID=secuence**. User may have more than 1 secuence and claims are done with one or more dates. So a user may have a claim for 6/7/2017 and secuence=22.  Also user may submit a claim with same date (6/7/2017) with secuence=9. User may even submit 2 diferent dates, with different secuences.
Need to validate if user has already submitted a claim for a Date, and secuence. So claims are not duplicated and an alert is triggered if it is already claimed.

To work this out: I´m doing a table/matrix where each secuence is assigned to a date already submitted. The objective is to get many date objects with each assigned secuence. So next entry is compared.

So first step:

claimList.get({workID: $rootScope.workID}, function(response) {
          listByDate = [];

```
        var validateList = response.body;
        validateList.forEach(function(response){          
          listByDate.push({
            key1: 'date',
            key2: 'Secuence',
            value1: response.date,
            value2: response.secuence
          });
```

}

BUilding this matrix is quite difficult

next step would be a foreach and conditional.

Comment: make fields required ?

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that data you're trying to store in is inside an object:

```
data = { date: x, sequence: y }
```

and data that you have already stored is inside an Array called `dataList`;

You should just check `dataList` for those values, if you can't find them it means you're safe and you can proceed by publishing a different and unique entry.

You should code something like the following

```
var occupiedSlot = dataList.find(
   function(elementOfDataList) {
      return elementOfDataList.date === data.date
   }
);
if(occupiedSlot) alert('You've already published an entry for this date!');
```

If you need to publish more entries, you can repeat this script inside a function for every entry that you need to check.